# Rigging a function to output a distinct value every nth call

Tags: functions, function-construction

There's some fixed script I am unable to alter (keeping things simple: `Table[f[i], {i, 1, 10}]`), , however, I can alter a function that the script calls (again, keeping things simple: `f := RandomInteger[{0, #}] &;`).

Again, without altering my script / command, I would like to rig `f` to do something like return `-#` every nth time it's called (with the counter starting from the first time its called during the execution of a script).

Is there a nice way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of...?

```
Clear[f];
f[]=0;
f[x_]:=(Set[f[],f[]+1]; If[f[]>=10,(Set[f[],0];-x),RandomInteger[{0,x}]]);
```